# QDialog with transparent background color

Tags: qt

I want to make the background of a `QDialog` transparent so that I can see through the window. I'm asking because I want to use a semi-transparent background image that creates a "rounded corner window" illusion. Using `setOpacity` is not an option for me because I want all widgets to remain at full opacity.

Is there a way to achieve this without resorting to native OS APIs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A qt widget with fully transparent background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278723/a-qt-widget-with-fully-transparent-background)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);`. Note that this also requires `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` to be set.

This example works for me:

```
#include <QtGui>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    Dialog() : QDialog(0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint) // hint is required on Windows
    {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Some Button", this);    
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog d;
    d.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Regarding rounded corners, `QWidget::setMask()` will help you.

EDIT: In response to another question below in the comments, here is a working example that uses an image in a resources file, and that overrides `QWidget::paintEvent()`:

```
#include <QtGui>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    Dialog() : QDialog(0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint) // hint is required on Windows
    {
        setFixedSize(500, 500); // size of the background image
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Some Button", this);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawImage(QRectF(0, 0, 500, 500), QImage(":/resources/image.png"));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog d;
    d.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this in conjunction with a background image that contains semi-transparent regions, but I noticed that the background image disappears when I make the background translucent. Are there any alternatives I should consider?

Comment: @Pieter I'm using Windows 7, and the code I posted doesn't make a drop shadow on my computer.