# Put transparent QWidget on top of QMediaView in QT5 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, video, user-interface, qt5

**Goal**

I want the background of my QT5 based GUI to be a video file that is playing. I also want to be able to style my GUI components with transparency so that the video will show through them.

I am not sure if this is at all possible to accomplish. It could be that i've just missed an important clue (I am after all a Qt beginner), or it could be that it just simply was not meant to work. But being an optimist, I have given it my best try.

**First attempt**

My minimal first attempt looked like this:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMediaPlayer *media=new QMediaPlayer(0);
    QVideoWidget *video=new QVideoWidget(0); //new QGLWidget()
    media->setVideoOutput(video);
    media->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/tmp/avatar.mp4"));
    media->setPosition(3000000);
    media->play();
    QPushButton *pb=new QPushButton(video);
    pb->setText(QString("BOB"));
    //pb->setStyleSheet(QString("background:transparent;"));
    video->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

The button is on top of the playing video, which is good. But if you look closely, you will see some black pixels in the corners of the button indicating that it is not transparent over the video, but rendered as an opaque rectangle.

[image: First result screenshot]

**Second attempt**

I tried styling the button with `background:transparent;` (see commented line in code above). This made the background of the button transparent, but the black box behind the button is now even more evident.

[image]

**Other attempts**

I have read several tips from various sources on-line on how to do this. None have worked for me. I have tried working with QGraphicsScene and friends, different stacks of layouts, different attributes on the widgets in question and many more. My last attempt was to set the parent of the QVideoWidget to an instance of QGLWidget() in the hope that forced hardware acceleration would solve my problems (my computer has hardware 3d acceleration with binary driver). This simply stopped the window from appearing at all, while I could still hear the soundtrack of the video playing in the background indicating that the application was still running.

**Request**

I really hope that there are some kindhearted and smart QT5 developers out there that can help me fulfill my dream of having widgets placed atop of a playing video in QT5 on Ubuntu.

Thank you!

Comment: I turned this in just about every way, and I don't think this is feasible - a bad regression from QT 4.8 IMHO. I placed a bounty on your question though, in the hope someone can enlighten us...

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion. I have since (rather reluctantly I must admit) converted parts of my application to QML/QtQuick 2.2 to solve this. This suddenly opened a whole new world of flexibility and productivity for us. Unfortunately this has also made our application dependent on the available GPU resources on target hardware. This has posed some problems of its own for us, but still we are happy to have converted. Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't turn to QML (insert libvlc reason). Interesting that it works though... Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question and you managed to solve your problem by converting parts of your application to QML/QtQuick 2.2 but I ended up bumping into it by google search and someone else with the same problem might also find this. I found a solution that worked for me and has been tested on Windows with QT 5.3.

What I did was use a QGraphicsView to display the video. Here's my code (playerScreen is the QGraphicsView):

```
QGraphicsVideoItem *item = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
item->setSize(ui->playerScreen->size());
player.reset(new QMediaPlayer());
player->setVideoOutput(item);
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, ui->playerScreen->size().width(), ui->playerScreen->size().height());
ui->playerScreen->setScene(scene);
ui->playerScreen->scene()->addItem(item);
```

I disabled the scroll bars on playerScreen otherwise there would be horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

I have a QWidget on top of the playerScreen in which I draw with QPainter. That QWidget is on top of the graphics view.

Then, when I play the video, I call `ui->playerScreen-show()`. I do this only on play because I have another screen on top (for another stuff related to my project) and I need to call show/hide when the video is being used/not used :)

Let me know if you need more information on my code.

Comment: Thanks dude! And for the record, improving uppon or adding to old questions is warmly welcomed here on s.o. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. If you end up testing it let me know how it goes for you. :)

Comment: I will. Ps: merry xmas

Comment: Good to hear that Rigel! :)

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have not tried this solution. It works on Qt 4.8 to put transparant widgets over anything that is OpenGL rendered. I am just assuming the media play is using hardware acceleration.

The black pixels are Qt's backbuffer where software rendering is performed. The video bypasses this backbuffer, and when a 'regular' qt widget is drawn, it draws on top of the backbuffer which is still in it's initial state (black).

You could make the button (or a widget containing the button) a separate, transparant window.

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::SplashScreen);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

You would need to position it manually though, so it follows your window.
This means the button needs to install an eventfilter on the window, and listen to any move or resize events. It then recalculates its own position, relative to the window, and updates it position.

Comment: This would in my book be considered a hack for the truly desperate (those for whom QtQuick is not an option). I am therefore reluctant to accept this as the correct answer, at least not before anyone can actually confirm that it will work. In practice this will ofload the whole responsibility of the compositing to the OS, which might not work reliably in all cases.

Answer (score -4):

[qwidget4.1](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.1/qwidget.html#transparency-and-double-buffering)

void    setAutoFillBackground(bool enabled) //you have that method, try it.

Always search in the forum before, cause there are a lot of answers. :) not that i mind, its faster for you.

[A qt widget with fully transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278723/a-qt-widget-with-fully-transparent-background)

Comment: Hi! I think you might have jumped to quickly on this one. You see, the buttons are transparent when I draw them over other widgets. The background video is the culprit here, due to some hardware acceleration of the area where the video is shown. I have really searched hard for a solution before posting my question, I have also been to the pages you suggested, and those are NOT the answers.

Comment: okay, my bad?.

I provided you what you needed,
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html

You did not read the document completely. There are some rendering flgs you can pass to you qpushbutton to get the background of the parent(if not specific).
Or using a Custom qpushbutton and reimplementing the methods.

Feel lazy... no code for now.

Comment: Did you read the link you provided? Quoting: "The left widget has no additional properties or widget attributes set. This default state suits most custom widgets using transparency, are irregularly-shaped, or do not paint over their entire area with an opaque brush". I can confirm this in my code, by moving the topmost widget away from the video and over another widget it looks exactly like it should, without the black background rectangle, letting the background shine through. I suggest you try it for yourself :)