# QT transparent button over QOpenGLWidget issue

Tags: qt, transparent, qwidget

I've made an transparent button over QOpenGLWidget, but I didn't get what I want. It's a little difference between the button image and its real expression.

Here is the original button image:

[image]

And Here is what I get:

[image]

I used Qss image property to set the image, but where does the greys come from? why the background color of the buttons in the second screenshot are not white?

Please let me know how can I do to fix this issue.

Comment: Please clarify what the difference is. If the images are important for the comprehension of the question, please add them embedded in the question.

Comment: How are you showing the images exactly?

Comment: @peppe They are two QPushButtons, images are set with Qss. Also the buttons layout inside an QFrame which is inherited from the QOpenGLWidget, and both of them over the OpenGL viewport.

Comment: After a lot of times google, I got the following thread.
[link1](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40335-QLabel-on-top-of-a-QGLWidget-background-issue) 
[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889319/put-transparent-qwidget-on-top-of-qmediaview-in-qt5-on-ubuntu)
But I still can't find a way to fix it.